# where is my "Create strongly-typed view" menu option in MVC 5 Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am starting to create MVC 5 applications. But in controller, right click inside Create action method, select Create View.  Menu comes up, where I can select model, etc., but there is no longer an option to select "Create strongly-typed view". See screenshot below

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 15):

Hi MVC3/ or Visual Studio 2015 does not give option to select 'Strongly typed view', instead following steps need to carry out to implement strongly typed views.

Build your project before starting following steps so that you will get model in the list to select as strongly type.

1. Right click on the controller to generate view.

[image]

2. By default you will see following screen

[image]

3. Change options from Template : Empty (without model) to 'Empty' like below

[image]

4. This will allow you to choose your 'Strongly typed' View.

[image]

5. When View is created it will look like following

[image]

Let me know in case of any queries.

Answer (score 4):

VS2013 changed the language a bit.  To create "strongly typed" view, trigger the create a view dialog and choose any template other than "Empty (without model)".  You should now be able to choose your Model from the "Model Class" dropdown.  Doing this will create the equivalent of a strongly typed view.

Comment: Note :- In case you are not able to see the model in the drop down , please compile your project once.

Comment: How do you trigger the create a view dialog?

Comment: @xr280xr you can Right Click -> Add View on either the Views folder or within an action in a controller file.