# Cannot access Controller properties in View using strongly typed view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, strongly-typed-view

I created a controller called Employeecontroller with the following function:

```
    Function Details() As ActionResult
        Dim myemployee As New Employee
        myemployee.Name = "John"
        Return View()
    End Function
```

After that I "Add a View" with the following settings:

```
View name: Details
Template: Empty
Model class
Employee(ProjeytName.Models)
```

According to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28349210/where-is-my-create-strongly-typed-view-menu-option-in-mvc-5-visual-studio-2013) a strongley typed view is generated. My View Code looks like:

```
@ModelType MVC_AdminTry1.Models.Employee
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Employee Details"
End Code
<h2>@Model.Name</h2>
```

Now I get a Null Reference Error pointing to @Model.Name but I just cannot see, what is wrong. Could anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the model to the View:

```
Return View(myemployee)
```